# Python Import Error not working

Tags: python, import

I currently have the following directory structure:

```
Folder/
  package/
      __init__.py, .. many python files
  subfolder/
       file1.py
```

Now, my problem is that I am in the `Folder` directory. I can run python and then run `import package`. This works fine. However, in my `file1.py`, I import `package` at the beginning but when I run `python subfolder/file1.py`, it cannot find module named `package`.

Edited: I currently have __ init__.py (with 2 underscores)

Comment: How do you import your package in file1.py ?

Comment: Renaming `_init_.py` to `__init__.py` should help you out

Comment: I suspect the underscores are a typo: the problem will remain even if they are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

In the latter case, Python cannot find `package` because it is not visible on `sys.path`. `sys.path` will contain amongst other things the parent directory of the script currently being executed.

So when you run Python from `Folder`, this entry is `/path/to/Folder` and `import package` correctly finds the `package` directory from this. In your second case, this entry will be `/path/to/Folder/subfolder` and `import package` will fail because it tries to find `/path/to/Folder/subfolder/package`.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without knowing what you're trying to achieve. You can manipulate `sys.path` inside a script to bring the right packages into scope (i.e. by adding `/path/to/Folder` to `sys.path` in `file1.py` before importing `package`), but often a rethink of your architecture is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `_init_.py` to `__init__.py` (two underscores)